# Strange Joomla Issues on VPS

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

Recently I moved my Joomla 3.3.6 site on VPS from shared hosting. Following are VPS configurations:

Vendor: GenuineIntel
Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU L5420 @ 2.50GHz
Speed: 2500.090 MHz
Cache: 6144 KB
1024 MB RAM

Our daily pageviews are Aprx 11k. Now having couple of issues:

- Gtmetrix score has been reduced on VPS
- Sometime site wont open normally (takes time to load)
- VPS Ram is always 30% +
- CPU is aprx 3% and suddenly it shoot to aprx 20% (and then site dont load)
- It takes time to open Clear Cache from menu. (Joomla cache is enabled from global configuration as well as cache plugin). So I renamed cache folder and created new cache folder and clear cache loading issue was resolved, but admintools is not working perfectly, specially fix permission shows empty pop up, then i revert to old cache folder and admin tools fix permission worked fine but when i click on clear cache from Joomla back end menu it takes too much time and this remained same.

Although site was working perfectly on shared hosting but i had bandwidth issue so moved on VPS.

Using following:

Joomla 3.3.6
K2 - updated
bigshoot plugin - latest
hwdmediashare - latest
Xmap - latest

I would appreciate if someone can assist, I believe something is wrong with vps, because i never ever had a single issue on shared hosting and gtmetrix score was good than now, and i did not make any changes in joomla on VPS.

Answer (score 1):

If your CPU is having 20% peaks, and the site does not load, something is going on. For instance, cache expires and a *mega-sql-query* consumes all available resources.

You can start deactivating your biggest content, looking for the source of the overhead. Try to explore the issue in a development site. In this way, you can parts of the site without affecting the live service.

Comment: Thank you for you response: I dont have any big content, except few K2 articles, and arounf 2500 embedded videos. CPU is always performing bad, site performance is very slow. I even contacted with hosting provider but they said VPS is fine, and i do believe that my Joomla site is fine. I dont know what to do :S

Comment: Well, 2500 videos in K2 articles is a start ;-) To test it, you can delete 2499 and check if you can find the issue.

Comment: thank you Anibal, my website is live and i cant do that. Thank Indeed

Comment: In these cases, where you can't find the issue, you have to duplicate the site and play with settings until you find it ... there is no "answer" ;-)